# How to develop a plugin for SonarQube 5.2

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

Can someone please suggest a good tutorial for developing plugin for SonarQube 5.2? I have tried searching for it but whatever I have found are based on sonar wsclient which is removed completely from 5.2 onward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Developing Plugins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+Plugins) guide on the [SonarQube Wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/).